# HTML Active Attribute

Tags: html

Buttons have a `disabled` attribute, which influences its native behaviour. Is it html-syntaxically incorrect to set a `active` attribute?

```
<button active></button>
```

For some reason, I'd like not to use the `class` attribute.

Comment: *"For some reason, I'd like not to use the class attribute."* Can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: Are you asking if specifying "active" is somehow the opposite of specifying "disabled"? No, it's not. The absence of "disabled" is enough for a button to be active.

Comment: Well, I see a button as a state machine, that can be disabled, normal or active. But I'm going to use `data-active` then.

Comment: @AugustinRiedinger Don't. That's a really bad idea, and it's not how buttons work, even if it's how you like to imagine it. Instead, actually use what buttons *really* provide, instead of something you want to pretend they provide. What, in your mind, is the difference between "normal" and "active"? Are you talking about a button being *focused*?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no "active" attribute.

A button that is not disabled is, by definition, "active".

It is not **syntactically** incorrect to specify arbitrary attributes on an element, but it *does* yield an invalid document.

When in doubt, try the [W3C HTML5 validator](http://validator.w3.org/).

```
Attribute active not allowed on element button at this point:
<button active></button>

Attributes for element button:
Global attributes
  autofocus
  disabled
  form
  formaction
  formenctype
  formmethod
  formnovalidate
  formtarget
  menu
  name
  type
  value
```